# Second JFrame closes first

Tags: java, swing, jframe

two `JFrame`s,

`JFrame Main; // Main JFrame`

`JFrame Sub; //Second JFrame that is initialized from within Main via a JMenuItems ActionListener.`

```
mainMenuItem.setActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try{
            Sub subFrame = new Sub();
            subFrame.setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is whenever i close the second JFrame (Sub) it closes the first aswell.

Both `JFrame`s have:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Is that part of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` by definition exits the application. For your second `Frame` use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` or `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` means to exit the program immediately (`System.exit()`) when the frame is closed.

You probably want to set this to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, then add a `WindowListener` and close the program only if both frames have been closed.

(Or, perhaps you want only the main frame to have `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`)

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> JFrame Sub; //Second JFrame that is initialized from within Main via a JMenuItems ActionListener.

This suggests you've a design problem:

- Your 2nd "frame" shouldn't even be a JFrame since it is not behaving as a separate independent main program window.
- Instead it's acting as a dialog since it is dependent on and shown from a parent window, the main JFrame. So make the secondary window a JDialog not a JFrame, and all these problems will go away.
- You will need to consider whether it should be a *modal* dialog where the main window is not accessable to the user while the dialog is open, or a *non-modal* dialog.
- Having said that, you may even be better off using one window/JFrame and swapping views via a CardLayout.

Please read this link: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice), and in particular please have a look at Andrew Thompson's community wiki answer.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realise it was bad practice to have multiple JFrames. I just want a pop up window with some text like the "about" window that most software contains where you see the version number etc. What would be a better way of doing this without another JFrame?

Comment: @clairharrison: again what you are trying to do is show a dialog window. The standard way to do this is as I describe above in my answer.